# How to create spark RDD from orc file in pyspark shell

Tags: pyspark, rdd, orc

I want to load a orc file from pyspark shell to create a hadoopRDD.

I am using below command in pyspark shell :

```
    >>> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    >>> conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
    >>> sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    >>> lines =sc.newAPIHadoopFile("/tmp/orcfile","org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.io.Text","org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable")
```

I am getting an error like below :

```
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopFile.
    : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat
```

Can anybody show me correct way to do it for Orc and sequence file.

I was able to create dataframe though from hiveContext:

```
    >>> orcfile = "/tmp/orcfile"
    >>> sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
    >>> read_orclines = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load(orcfile)
    >>> read_orclines.first()
```